# How to serialize an array to a string in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In a website built with Django I've got a model which has a `CharField`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The CharField can contain a list of strings which are comma separated. For example: `ADC,HJD,RTP`

Using [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) I created a POST endpoint to which people can post new records. That field is posted in json as an array though. So the json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 25,
    "categories": ["ADC", "HJD", "RTP"]
}
```

I wanted to simply `join()` the array in the `Serializer` `create()` method. But it never reaches that point because it gets filtered out by the validator. I guess the validation is done in the view, but I'm unsure where to start digging.

Does anybody know how I can make the endpoint accept an array and turn it into a comma separated string in a CharField?

[EDIT]

These are my ViewSets:

```
class DevicesViewSet(DatapuntViewSetWritable):
    queryset = Device.objects.all().select_related('owner', 'contact').prefetch_related('types').order_by('id')

    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
    serializer_detail_class = DeviceSerializer

    http_method_names = ['post', 'list', 'get']


class ContactViewSet(CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Device.objects.none()
    serializer_class = IotContactSerializer
    pagination_class = None
```

Comment: Do you want to concatenate what is in the array to string and save to DB?

Comment: @MenilikBelay - Yes, indeed. That is what I want to do.

Comment: can you show your view please? That is where the logic should be

Comment: @MenilikBelay - I added the Views I have to the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edited question, here is what you can do. Inherit in your view viewsets.ViewSet and override the create method and write your concatenation logic. [Check here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

```
class CreatePersonViewSet (viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
         """
         Do your logic here... to create
         """
         pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess that would work, but doesn't that completely disregard all the validations which are done?

Comment: Your class based view can check the stated validations you want. What kind of validation are you interested on?